# Create new dataframe with tuple of cartesian product of few columns as one column and keep remaining columns from the same row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with values like this:

```
  |  From  | Tran type | Inv type |  Opposite   |    Comment   | Other values |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0 | Seller |     X     |   P, Q   |    Buyer    |   Comment 1  |    Value 2   |
1 | Seller |   Y, Z    |    R     |    Buyer    |   Comment 3  |    Value 4   |
2 | Seller |   A, B    |   NaN    |    Buyer    |   Comment 5  |    Value 5   |
```

From this df, I want to create a new one like so:

```
  |           Combos         |   Comment    | Other values |
---------------------------------------------------------
0 |   (Seller, X, P, Buyer)  |  Comment 1   |   Value 2    |
1 |   (Seller, X, Q, Buyer)  |  Comment 1   |   Value 2    |
2 |   (Seller, Y, R, Buyer)  |  Comment 3   |   Value 4    |
3 |   (Seller, Z, R, Buyer)  |  Comment 3   |   Value 4    |
4 |  (Seller, A, nan, Buyer) |  Comment 5   |   Value 5    |
5 |  (Seller, B, nan, Buyer) |  Comment 5   |   Value 5    |
```

I tried using df.apply. For each row, I find cartesian product of the 4 columns. Iterated through those and created a single line `single_df` along with the remaining columns, and append this to `row_df` which should finish with a df of all possible combinations of the 4 variables for 1 row. I then return this `row_df` in the function. I call this function on the overall df, and update to another `total_df`.

However, I got the error `TypeError: Can only append a Series if ignore_index=True or if the Series has a name`. I printed out the type of the return value from my function and got DataFrame, so I'm not sure why it says append a Series.

What am I doing wrong? And is there a better approach?

Apologies for not attaching the code, it was edited by my teammate overnight and previous version wasn't saved.

EDIT: Added in rows when `NaN` appears in `Inv type` column. I want the tuples to contain the values as strings, so 'nan' will be stored as a string.

Comment: Can you include the datatypes with `df.info()`?

Comment: I'm reading the df from an excel file. df.info() gives all dtypes as object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other way using `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product

def cartesian(x):
    return list(product(*[i.split(", ") for i in x]))

cols = ["From", "Tran type", "Inv type", "Opposite"]
df["Combos"] = df[cols].astype(str).apply(cartesian, 1)
print(df.drop(cols, 1).explode("Combos").reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
     Comment Other values                   Combos
0  Comment 1      Value 2    (Seller, X, P, Buyer)
1  Comment 1      Value 2    (Seller, X, Q, Buyer)
2  Comment 3      Value 4    (Seller, Y, R, Buyer)
3  Comment 3      Value 4    (Seller, Z, R, Buyer)
4  Comment 5      Value 5  (Seller, A, nan, Buyer)
5  Comment 5      Value 5  (Seller, B, nan, Buyer)
```

Comment: I'm reading in an excel file using pd.read_excel. This code gives me "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'". Running with different values in cols variable shows that this occurs in 'Inv type' column. Apologies, I should have mentioned that 'Inv type' can potentially have null ('nan') values, which is the case with 'Inv type' here. The remaining 3 in cols do not have null values, but the other columns do as well

Comment: @ArjunSrinivasan In such case where some element is `NaN`,  what do you want to do? Do you skip the row? Do you fill it with something else? Perhaps it would be better if you add such race condition to the sample as well ;)

Comment: @ArjunSrinivasan Check my edit. Since you want to treat `NaN` as an element, all you need to do is add `astype(str)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution, [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas-series-str-split) by delimiter & [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html#pandas-dataframe-explode) the dataframe for replicating rows.

```
df['Tran type'] = df['Tran type'].fillna('').str.split(",")
df['Inv type'] = df['Inv type'].fillna('').str.split(",")

df_join = df.explode(column="Tran type").explode(column="Inv type")

combos = ['From', 'Tran type', 'Inv type', 'Opposite']

(df_join.assign(
        Combos = df_join[combos].apply(lambda x: tuple(x), axis=1))
        .drop(columns=combos))
```

---

```
     Comment Other values                    Combos
0  Comment 1      Value 2     (Seller, X, P, Buyer)
0  Comment 1      Value 2    (Seller, X,  Q, Buyer)
1  Comment 3      Value 4     (Seller, Y, R, Buyer)
1  Comment 3      Value 4    (Seller,  Z, R, Buyer)
2  Comment 5      Value 5   (Seller, A, NaN, Buyer)
2  Comment 5      Value 5  (Seller,  B, NaN, Buyer)
```

Comment: Tried this exact code. I still have the same number of rows, only difference is that the 4 columns have been replaced and the new `Combos` column now holds `(Seller, X, P, Q, Buyer)` in the first row. Similarly for the rest. Please check my edit in case that changes your solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [df.explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to create the additional rows and then join the columns if you must.

```
df = df.explode('Tran type', ignore_index=True).explode('Inv type', ignore_index=True)
df['Combos'] = df.From + ',' + df['Tran type'] + ',' + df['Inv type'] + ',' + df.Opposite
```

Keeping the columns separated might speed up lookups and filters later on.